# Choose which Airport to connect to

Tags: wifi, airport

I have an Airport Extreme on one floor and another one on the second floor as an extender. For some reason my device keeps connecting to the first floor Extreme - I know this because I can see it in the Airport Utility. How can I change this?

Comment: Do both of your Airports support 2.4 and 5Ghz?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is give them the same name, but dial down the transmit power for each.

The current AirPort Utility (the 6.x version) doesn't support this, but the old 5.6.x version can still be downloaded here:
http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/10/24/airport-utility-5-6-1-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/

Comment: Until I added a WiFi card to my Mac Pro, that's what I used to try to make the phones/pads pick the right connection. They still insisted on trying to connect to the far one, even when it was struggling to even find it at 25% power. Adding the WiFi to the Mac allowed me to swap priority & the phones have followed suit. [Ugh, just checked... they haven't - but the Mac does]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the priority in System Prefs > Network - select WiFi on the left, then Advanced... bottom right.
Drag the available connections into the order you prefer...

[image]